# mkssecreenshotmgr taking a screenshot

Tags: windows, operating-system, vmware

I see this message in log file of windows
`mks-vmdb vmdb requested a screenshot svga mkssecreenshotmgr taking a screenshot`

Anyone have explanation for this log
And i need to know if could  this related to any suspicious activity
Thanks for the explanation